# Prevent portrait mode after phone lock

Tags: android, android-manifest, orientation

I have an application with four activities, one of them should be fixed to landscape mode. If I am viewing the landscape-activity, lock my phone and unlock it again, the activity appears for a short time in portrait mode and then turns to landscape mode.
How can I prevent the short moment of portrait mode after unlocking the phone?

This is my manifest where the screen orientation is specified:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".add" />
    <activity android:name=".kats" />
    <activity
        android:name=".game"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 elements, first in you Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="Activity"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
...
</activity>
```

In your Activity:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```